# SyntaxError: invalid syntax for breaking a true while and print a cod

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I want to print the "bye"  after breaking the True while, but  I'm having trouble.
Here is my code

```
while (True) :
    number = (input("pleas enter a number : \n"))
    if number == ("don") :
          break and print("bye") 
    else: 
        number = int(number)
        if number%2 == 0 :
            print("even")
        else :
            print("Odd")
```

and this is the ful error:

```
line 4
    print("bye") and break   
                   ^^^^^   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

All this code is to distinguish even and odd numbers received from the user.
My goal was to write an true while to receive an infinite number of numbers from the user, and when the user uses the "don" command, this loop end and show the "bye" message to the user.
But this code encountered an error and the program did not run

Comment: You don't  `break and print("bye") `. Just print('bye') and move the break statement to the next line

Comment: "and" is not used to do two things.  "a and b" does not mean "do a then do b".  Instead, it is an operator, like "+" or "*".  It returns true if both a and b are true.

Answer (score 1):

`break` is not an expression and cannot appear as an operand to `and`. Instead write those two steps explicitly.

Also, you can remove a lot of unnecessary parens from your code.

```
while True:
    number = input("please enter a number : \n")
    if number == "don":
        print("bye")
        break
    else: 
        number = int(number)
        if number % 2 == 0:
            print("even")
        else:
            print("Odd")
```

And since `int(number)` is only called once and it's value is never needed again afterwards:

```
while True:
    number = input("please enter a number : \n")
    if number == "don":
        print("bye")
        break
    elif int(number) % 2 == 0:
        print("even")
    else:
        print("Odd")
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` is a statement, not an expression, so you can't combine it with something else using `and`.

To do two things in an `if`, put them on separate lines.

```
    if number == "don":
        print("bye")
        break
```